# Changing a View (ProgressBar) visibility from within an OnClick Anonymous Inner Class inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a ProgressBar in the layout of a Fragment that I want to set to Visible at the beggining of an OnClick method of a Button, and then back to Gone at the end of the method:

```
public class ProfileTab extends Fragment {


private Button update;
private ProgressBar wait;
```

which I initialize in OnCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_tab_layout, container, false);

        update= v.findViewById(R.id.Update);

        wait = v.findViewById(R.id.WaitUpdateInfo);
        //wait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //wait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                /*
                   Code to execute during OnCLick
                */

                wait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

I have checked and I am sure the visibility of *wait* never changes during the OnClick method. However, it DOES change during the *OnCreateView* if I uncomment the pertinent code.

Also, trying this same scenario in a regular Activity (a button and a ProgressBar, initialized and assigned the OnClick method in the Activity's OnCreate), the visibility is modified both in the *Oncreate* method **AND** on the execution of *OnClick*, so I can only guess there is some behaviour relative to Fragments that I'm not managing to catch...

Comment: `onClick` handlers run in the UI thread, so the UI on the screen can't update in the middle of the method. Instead, it will wait until the end of the method, at which point the visibility is set to `GONE`. What are you trying to do while the view is visible? Perhaps you could use an AsyncTask to do that work in a background thread and then update the visibility once you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClick` runs on the Main UI thread. Your view will not be updated until this logic has completed. You update the `wait` view in `OnClick`, but that change will not be visible until the `OnClick` method has completed, and the UI is updated. At the end of your `OnClick` method, nothing has changed with the `wait` view (remains `GONE`, as it was at the start of the method). Try running your logic off of the main thread. `AsyncTask` is designed for this paradigm https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask:

```
private class DoWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        wait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        /*
           Code to execute while wait is visible
        */

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        wait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

...

update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DoWork doWork = new DoWork();
        doWork.execute();
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, you were absolutely right! I didn't realize that in a similar code in my MainActivity, I placed the wait.setVisibility(View.Gone) INSIDE of a background-running method in my Onclick, so it behaved like it was supposed to. In the Onclick of my Fragment, I placed it AFTER the background-running method, so it would immediatly re-hide the Progressbar while the rest of the code was still running. Gotta learn to be more careful with Threads, thanks!